# UITableView background view auto resizing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to have a little red square at the center of my tableView (tableView.backgroundView) that does not fill the tableView. but according to apple

> When you assign a view to this property, the table view automatically
> resizes that view to match its own bounds.

So there is no way to prevent this resizing and filling the tableViewBackgroundView?

Comment: You can add constraint to your small red square view to a generic UIView as required. And add that generic view to backgroundView of the tableView. You can also set the background Color of that generic view to UIColor.clear. So that it will not effect the actual background Color of TableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@[finebel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64229327/10175156) solution is completely fine. But if you are searching for something different. Here you go

You can add this bgView to the tableView directly and send this new subview to back. 
This way you can retain background color of your table view as well.

```
// after your setup
let bgView = UIView()
tableView.addSubview(bgView)
// add constraints after disabling autoresizing mask
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
tableView.sendSubview(toBack: bgView)
```

Comment: Why i did not test the constraints before asking question :)) Thanks

Comment: After reading other comments I got to know, you are adding a reload button when data is not loading correctly. In that case, you shouldn't sendSubviewToBack instead, you should consider bringToFront. Use these methods wisely! I hope you achieved what you intended to.

Comment: Yes i remove the sendSubviewToBack and everything work fine now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `backgroundView` attribute you could add a subview below your `tableView` like so:

```
//for example inside viewDidLoad()

let bgView = UIView()
bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.insertSubview(bgView, belowSubview: tableView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    bgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
    bgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    bgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    bgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
])

bgView.backgroundColor = .red
```

But in order to see `bgView` you will have to set `tableView.backgroundColor = .clear`. In addition your `UITableViewCells` should have a clear background too.

[image]

Comment: Actually i want to place a Reload button in tableView when data does not load properly in tableView, so i think it should not be under tableView so it is not clickable any more, but thanks for your good approach <3

Comment: @Mahdiyar tableview should be hidden in this case and un hide another view.